# Umbraco 7 - Get property from one page to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, razor, umbraco7

Im new to umbraco 7

I have a Masterpage - Inside I have 2 **Partialviews** - `HEADER` & `FOOTER`

I have 2 subpages that inherites from Masterpage - **`HOME PAGE`** & **`STANDARD PAGE`**

Inside `HOME PAGE - Document Type` I have a **`Reletad Links`** property

The code for the **`Releted Links`** property is inside a Partialview called **`Links`**

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

@{
    if (Model.Content.HasValue("externalLinks") && Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<string>("externalLinks").Length > 2)
    {
        <ul>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<JArray>("externalLinks"))
            {
                var linkTarget = item.Value<bool>("newWindow") ? "_blank" : null;

                if (Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<JArray>("externalLinks").First() == item)
                {
                    <li>
                        <a href="@(item.Value<string>("link"))" target="@linkTarget"> <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> @(item.Value<string>("caption"))</a>
                    </li>
                }
                else
                {
                    <li>
                        <a href="@(item.Value<string>("link"))" target="@linkTarget"> <i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i> @(item.Value<string>("caption"))</a>
                    </li>
                }
            }
        </ul>
    }
}
```

The **`LINKS`** partialview is loaded inside the **`HEADER`** partialview

The code is working fine when navigating to **`HOME PAGE`** but If I go to **`STANDARD PAGE`** then the **`Reletad Links`** property is no loger visible.

What can I do to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of referencing the current page (through Model.Content) you'll want to reference the homepage

I've added a bit of code to the PartialView to illustrate it, haven't tested it though

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

@{
    // First get the homepage by traversing the Umbraco tree and searching for the homepage node
    var homepage = Umbraco.TypedContentAtRoot().First().DescendantsOrSelf().FirstOrDefault(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias == "home");
    if (homepage != null && homepage.HasValue("externalLinks") && homepage.GetPropertyValue<string>("externalLinks").Length > 2)
    {
        <ul>
            @{
                var externalLinks = homepage.GetPropertyValue<JArray>("externalLinks");
                foreach (var item in externalLinks)
                {
                    var linkTarget = item.Value<bool>("newWindow") ? "_blank" : null;

                    if (externalLinks.First() == item)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <a href="@(item.Value<string>("link"))" target="@linkTarget"> <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> @(item.Value<string>("caption"))</a>
                        </li>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <li>
                            <a href="@(item.Value<string>("link"))" target="@linkTarget"> <i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i> @(item.Value<string>("caption"))</a>
                        </li>
                    }
                }
            }
        </ul>
    }
}
```